# Can't disable Jboss public ip in Jelastic

Tags: nginx, jboss, jboss7.x, jelastic

[image]

I enabled Jboss public IP so I could access it from FTP. But I'm not using it anymore and it's paid, so I want do disable it. But when I do it, after restarting each node, they get inaccessible. I don't understand why only after restarting them, it happens. If it worked before enabling it, it should work after disabling. Support has no ideia whats going on. Probably some configuration on Jboss But I couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you modify jboss configuration, or is it default? What about nginx config - is that connecting to jboss using the internal IPs (default) or did you customise it?

Comment: @Camilla Can we reproduce this issue on your environment? Also, note, you use wrong environment configuration IPv4 + Jelastic SSL https://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-ssl

Comment: @Damien, I think I didn't customized. Do you know where I can check it?

Comment: @Jelastic, I'm sorry. I couldn't see where it is wrong. Can you be more specific? Thank you :)

Comment: @Camilla, You can find this statement at the very end of the mentioned article: Jelastic SSL will be disabled if you switch on IPv4 for any node in your environment. And could you please clarify if we can reproduce the issue on your environment, detach/attach IPs, restart, etc?

Comment: @Jelastic, my ssl is still working. Yes, you can reproduce. Every time I do the same steps the problem occurs. I edit the environment, turning ipv4 off. Wait for the changes to be applied. Everything is still ok. If right after or hours later I restart the jboss nodes, the site gets unavailable. To get it available again, I do the same steps but turning on IPV4.

Comment: @Camilla, We were able to see some errors in logs. They could be related to firewall settings. We were testing our assumption but during the tests you attached IPs back. Can we get permission to reproduce the issue again. Expected downtime is up to 1h.

Comment: @Jelastic yes, you have the permission. I haven't seen this message before. As I didn't know how long it was expected to be down, I turned it on. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Camilla, restart of iptables in Nginx balancer seems to be fixed the issue. Could you please check from your side and let us know?

Comment: @Jelastic, it's working!!! Thank you so much! It's great to know that Jelastic has a great team actively working in stack overflow. :)

Comment: @Camilla, You're welcome! Glad to know we were able to help you :)